# Qt Android Extras installation

Tags: android, qt, module

I am developing an app that need to access the `image gallery` of the OS in `iOS` and `Android`.

I have seen that I must develop one way to `Android` using `QAndroidJniObject Class` and another way to `iOS` using the `UIKit` and `UIImagePickerController` from nativa `iOS` API.

So I decided to start with `Android` and I am facing a problem. When I include in my .pro file the line `QT += androidextras` it returns my the following error:
`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: androidextras`

Now I am trying to find out from where I can download it because the repositories at Qt site leads me to web pages that don't exist. How can I download that module?

Thanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To avoid that error when building for iOS, use a condition: `android: QT += androidextras`
2. Make sure that you are actually building for Android
3. Run `qmake`

That should fix it. If not, check if the files exist in your Qt-Install-Directory (e.g. `libQt5AndroidExtras.so`). If not, your installation of Qt is probably broken.